# InvalidPolicyConfig: Module for policy ‘KerasPolicy’ could not be loaded. Please make sure the name is a valid policy

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core

I am quite new to Rasa 2.0 and I have encountered this error message when I input

```
harper$ rasa train
```

Error message:

InvalidPolicyConfig: Module for policy ‘KerasPolicy’ could not be loaded. Please make sure the name is a valid policy.

I know that this question has been asked by someone else, and I have tried their solution of downgrading TensorFlow to its 1.15.0 version.

However, When I did that, it gave me the error that says

“ERROR: After October 2020 you may experience errors when installing or updating packages. This is because pip will change the way that it resolves dependency conflicts.

We recommend you use --use-feature=2020-resolver to test your packages with the new resolver before it becomes the default.
rasa 2.0.2 requires tensorflow<2.4,>=2.3, which is not installed."

If I understand this correctly, TensorFlow 1.15.0 is no longer compatible with rasa 2.0.

When I install TensorFlow 2.3.0 back, the first error message appeared again
: "InvalidPolicyConfig: Module for policy ‘KerasPolicy’ could not be loaded. Please make sure the name is a valid policy."

I was wondering if anyone has encountered similar issues specifically with rasa 2.0? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Keras policy was deprecated in Rasa 2.0 instead use TED policy. You’ll need to modify this in the `config.yml` file. You can find a full list of supported policies here: https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/policies
I’m including a sample config file below compatible with Rasa 2.0.

```
language: en

pipeline:
- name: WhitespaceTokenizer
- name: RegexFeaturizer
- name: LexicalSyntacticFeaturizer
- name: CountVectorsFeaturizer
- name: CountVectorsFeaturizer
  analyzer: char_wb
  min_ngram: 1
  max_ngram: 4
- name: DIETClassifier
  epochs: 100
- name: EntitySynonymMapper
- name: ResponseSelector
  epochs: 100
- name: FallbackClassifier
  threshold: 0.3
  ambiguity_threshold: 0.1

policies:
- name: MemoizationPolicy
- name: TEDPolicy
  max_history: 5
  epochs: 10
```

You should upgrade the rasa installation using pip in order to ensure its dependencies are up-to-date:

`pip install —upgrade rasa`